# How to use two defaultNetwork: in Hardhat.config.ts

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, web3-providers

Here's my `hardhat.config.ts` file

```
{
      defaultNetwork: 'goerli', //////// here 'polygon_mumbai'
      networks: {
        hardhat: {
        },
        localhost : {
          url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8545',
          accounts : [local_network_pvk]
        },
        goerli: {
          url: 'etH_RPC_URL_HERE',
          accounts: [admin_private_key_eth],
        },
        polygon_mumbai: {
          url: 'POLYGON_RPC_URL',
          accounts: [admin_private_key_eth],
        },
      },
      solidity: {
        version: '0.8.17',
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },
        },
      },
      paths: {
        sources: "./src/blockchain-utils/ethereum/contracts",
        tests: "./src/blockchain-utils/ethereum/test",
        cache: "./src/blockchain-utils/ethereum/cache",
        artifacts: ".src/blockchain-utils/ethereum/hh-artifacts"
      },
      mocha: {
        timeout: 40000
      }
    };
```

I want to run smart contracts of both Polygon and Eth how to configure the hardhatconfig file???

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have multiple default networks in your `hardhat.config.js`.
The `defaultNetwork` is used to specify which network should be used, in case there is no network specified when you execute `npx hardhat ...` in your terminal.
The `defaultNetwork` needs to be configured in the `networks` object, like in the example code you provided (the `defaultNetwork` is set to `goerli`).

If you want to run another network than the default one, you can just run `npx hardhat run --network goerli ...` or `npx hardhat run --network polygon_mumbai ...`

Additionally: you also can't run multiple networks simultaneously within a single command in hardhat, but you can run each network in separate terminals. You can run a script for the `polygon_mumbai` network in one terminal, and then run a different script for the `goerli` network in another terminal.

Comment: There is a npm package named "hardhat-change-network" we can use that to change the Network using Script without using cli

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package named "hardhat-change-network" we can use that to change the Network using Script without using cli
Just install and use :
hre.changeNetwork('goerli');